# The parameters of functions magically match up in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm new to angualarjs and just start to build a page using angularjs 1.5 component. I'm trying to understand the following example from pluralsight. Does angularjs extended javascript with partial application/currying and others?

**movie-rating.component.html:**
function `model.setRating()` is passed with an object with property of `value`.

```
<span ng-repeat="entry in model.entries track by $index">
    <span ng-click="model.setRating({ value: $index + 1})" class="glyphicon {{entry}}">
    </span>
</span>
```

**movie-rating.component.js:**
the `setRating` is bound using "&".

```
module.component("movieRating", {
    templateUrl: "/ps-movies/movie-rating.component.html",
    bindings: {
        value: "<",
        max: "<",
        setRating: "&"
    },
```

**movie-list.component.html:**
However, when using the component, the `set-rating` is assigned a function with *two* paramters `model.setRating(movie, value)`? And movie is actually a value from `<tr ng-repeat="movie in model.movies">`? but `value`?

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in model.movies">
    <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
    <td>{{movie.length}}</td>
    <td>
      <movie-rating value="movie.rating" max="5" set-rating="model.setRating(movie, value)">
      </movie-rating>
    </td>
```

**movie-list.component.js:**
And in the following code `model.setRating = function(movie, rating)`, there is no parameter that supposes to an object with property of `value`?

```
function controller($http) {
    var model = this;
    model.movies = [];

    model.$onInit = function() {
        fetchMovies($http).then(function(movies) { model.movies = movies; });
    };

    model.upRating = function(movie) { if(movie.rating < 5) { movie.rating += 1; } };
    model.downRating = function(movie) { if(movie.rating > 1) { movie.rating -= 1; } };

    model.setRating = function(movie, rating) { // rating is int, and movie is string
        movie.rating = rating;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS, the expressions bound by `&` are not executed in parameter order. Instead, when you execute a function bound like this, you have to execute it with an object. Let's take your example,

```
<movie-rating set-rating='model.setRating(movie, value)'></movie-rating>
```

Now, your `movie-rating` component will receive a `setRating` function and assign it to its controller. When you execute `$ctrl.setRating()` inside of the `movieRating` controller, Angular is going to expect you to pass it an object like

```
{ movie: 0, value: 0 }
```

it will then map these values to the parameter order specified in the string passed to `set-rating`; in other words, Angular will take `model.setRating(movie, value)` and work out that it actually needs to pass in the value of the `movie` key from the passed object to the first parameter and the `value` object to the second parameter.

So, when you click your `span` inside of `movie-rating`, it will call `setRating({ value: $index })`. It will leave `movie` `undefined`, so the parent function, `movieList.setRating` will receive the parameters `(undefined, $index)`.

Note that all of this expression binding behaviour (where the names of `movie` and `value` inside of the `set-rating` expression are preserved) only applies to the template. This is why in JavaScript code you see that Angular does not fall over.

---

To basically tldr this, when you use value names in a function binding in the template, Angular will unpack an object passed to an invocation of the function and match up the parameters via name. It will only do this for `&` bindings, and only unpack js objects to `&` bindings (which have to be defined in HTML). It will not unpack JS objects to regular JS functions (which makes sense - the HTML bindings won't be mangled, but JS variable names will be mangled at runtime; this is why you need to use $inject or array syntax for dependency injection in Angular)

let me know if I can explain this any clearer

Comment: here is some more readings from angularjs.org site: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-, see paragraph starting with '& or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope.'